# Splitting array into smaller arrays with maximum "chunks"

Tags: vb.net

I wonder if there is a nuget that can do this already

Anyway, here is my code

```
Public Shared Function splitArrayIntoSmallerArrays(Of someObject)(arrayOfSomeObject As someObject(), chunkSize As Integer) As List(Of someObject())

    Dim output = New List(Of someObject())
    Dim newestArray = New List(Of someObject)
    For i = 0 To arrayOfSomeObject.Count - 1

        newestArray.Add(arrayOfSomeObject(i))
        If newestArray.Count = chunkSize Then
            output.Add(newestArray.ToArray)
            newestArray = New List(Of someObject)
        End If
    Next
    If newestArray.Count > 0 Then
        output.Add(newestArray.ToArray)
    Else
        Dim b = 1
    End If

    Return output
End Function
```

The code will take a list and split it into several chunks.

I am looking for something more elegant like using something built in by someone else.

Comment: I think you don't understand what the Code Review Community is about. We review your code from a working project to help you improve your coding ability. This means that we make insightful observations about the code. Please read our help section starting with [How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I am voting to close this question because it doesn't seem to be asking for a code review and because the code is too theoretical.

Comment: .NET 6 includes [`Enumerable.Chunk`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.chunk?view=net-6.0) in LINQ

Comment: Ah that's what I want to know. Thanks @VisualMelon

Answer (score 2):

I think it is a more common convention to use "T" as a generic type parameter, and some of the other names can be updated to be clearer like "array" instead of "arrayOfSomeObject".

I also removed the Else block that declares a variable without using it and added a "clear" method to clear the list instead of making a new one.

```
Public Shared Function SplitArrayIntoSmallerArrays(Of T)(array As T(), chunkSize As Integer) As List(Of T())
    Dim output = New List(Of T())
    Dim newestArray = New List(Of T)
    For i = 0 To array.Count - 1
        newestArray.Add(array(i))
        If newestArray.Count = chunkSize Then
            output.Add(newestArray.ToArray())
            newestArray.Clear()
        End If
    Next
    If newestArray.Count > 0 Then
        output.Add(newestArray.ToArray())
    End If
    Return output
End Function
```

Comment: If someone has indicated the question is off-topic, please refrain from answering the question.

Comment: But it's a good answer. It's more elegant than mine. I love it